# getActivity() returns null inside fragment shakelistener

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code works fine most the times but sometimes getActivity() inside my shake listener is null. I'm sure that the fragment is attached to the activity because i execute some others update to it's UI before the shake happens. Moreover i attach the listener inside the onActivityCreated method that ensures that activity is created and the fragment is attached to.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ShakeListener mShaker = new ShakeListener(getActivity());
    mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
        public void onShake()
        {
            ImageView next_App = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.next_app); 
            Animation next_move = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.next); 
            next_App.startAnimation(next_move);
        }
    });
}
```

I can't figure out this issue, also with the many others questions answered, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: which class are you extending and on what device do you have this issue?

Comment: is getActivity().findViewById returning null??

Comment: It is common, fragments get detached from the activity. add a check using `isAdded()` before using `getActivity()`

Comment: BTW, you should probably keep next_App and next_move as member variables of your class that get inflated whenever your activity is created, and not every time on onShake. It should make the animation start with less delay, because you don't waste time inflating and loading resources each time.

Comment: @blackbelt the fragment extends SherlockFragment and the problem happens on 2.3 devices but works fine on 4.* device.

Comment: Cast your activity as `(youractivityname)getActivity()`

Comment: with @npace suggestion it works but i did not understand because the fragment get detached

Answer (score 1):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940409/1428624)

Fragments get detached from the activity and hence `getActivity()` sometimes returns null.
Add a check for `getActivity != null` or better check `isAdded()` before `getActivity()`.