# How can i rename a buttons / textviews text in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to rename different things (Buttons and Textviews) in a app from the code.

But because those are in a fragment for a Tabview this wont work and will lead to a crash:

```
someTextview.setText("some Text");
```

I have tried [this Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295101/how-to-change-fragments-textviews-text-from-activity) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559124/android-set-text-of-textview-in-fragment-that-is-in-fragmentpageradapter), but both solutions didnt work.

Is there something else that i could try?

Comment: what do you mean? from where? Do you want to change texts inside activity or fragment?

Comment: post your code. what you have tried. then it will be easier to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreateView()` function first inflate the view like this
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);`
then

```
   TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ANINRHinten);

   txtview.setText("Something");
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying but i always get the error: 'error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to byte[]
        View view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, page, false);'  

Maybe i am using the wrong layout...

Comment: can you paste your whole `onCreateView()` function?

Comment: I got it now. I just used the wrong coCreateView function. I used the one of the main activity instead of the fragment onCreateView function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In what function is that code? What error have you get?

have you take the id of that textview? we need more information.

Btw, if you create a variable like this on your onCreateView

```java
button = findViewById(R.id.idOfTheButton)
```

then you can use it on youre OnViewCreated like you wrote in the question.

```java
button.setText("text")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the .setText inside the onCreate main function, as well as the functions in the fragment class.

I didn't get any errors at all. If the setText is in the main onCreate function it compiles and opens on the simulator but crashes before doing anything.

When i tried to use it in the fragment function onCreateView, the app functions without any crashes or errors, but also the setText had no effect.

I have done the whole thing like you said from the start:

```
TextView txtview;

//Inside void onCreate:
       txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ANINRHinten);
    
       txtview.setText("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your textView?
If you didn't you can define it like below :

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
textView.setText("")
```

or if you use binding define it and use it like :

```
binding.textView.setText("")
```

Comment: Yes i did define the TextView, but this wasn't working from the Start.

Answer (score 0):

I started programing with Java and Android Studio a week ago, so feel free to tell me what else i can improve.

```
private TextView waitForConn;
private TabLayout maintab;
private ViewPager page;
private TabItem  tablicht, tabadmin;
public PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    /*For future implementations of BLE
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    waitForConn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wait_for_connection);
    waitForConn.setText("Suche Schnapsiinator...");
    waitForConn.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    waitForConn.setText("Verbinden...");
    waitForConn.setText("Verbunden");
    */

    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    maintab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tablicht = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.licht_tab);
    tabadmin = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.admin_tab);
    page = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_lichtadmin);

   pagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), maintab.getTabCount());
    page.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    //Compiler says  "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to byte[]"
    View view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, page, false);
    //at:                                ^

    maintab.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            page.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

   page.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(maintab));
}
```