# Sugar ORM: Class cast exception when trying to cast a context from getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, sugarorm

I tried to cast a context to an Activity. I need to do this to call one of that activity's method. To get the context I need, I used getApplicationContext(). The application that I am developing right now is using Sugar ORM as the database framework. Here is the code and the exception that I got.

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(((MainActivity) getApplicationContext()).getAccount(), AccountHelper.AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orm.SugarApp cannot be cast to id.ac.ui.presentronik.activity.MainActivity
        at id.ac.ui.presentronik.activity.SessionActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SessionActivity.java:173)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:44)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:163)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:738)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

It seems that the problem I encountered is same with one in this question: [SugarORM in AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354916/sugarorm-in-androidmanifest). But the solution only works with a Fragment. Is there any other way to get a correct context from an Activity?

Comment: any solution for this facing same issue here..

Answer (score 0):

> com.orm.SugarApp cannot be cast to
>   id.ac.ui.presentronik.activity.MainActivity

Pass in getActivity() as the context:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(getActivity().getAccount(), AccountHelper.AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
```

## OR

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(((com.orm.SugarApp) getApplicationContext()).getAccount(), AccountHelper.AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
```

Remember in your manifest you set something like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
```

You also need to use these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```