# Refresh RecyclerView in Activity after adding new data in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

1. Activity with recycerView set on it, and activity starts fragment to insert new data.

   ```
   getSupportFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.dialog_drop, R.anim.dialog_rise_up)
   .replace(R.id.frame_layout, dropDownDialogue)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .commit();`
   ```
2. Fragment has a save button that ends the fragment as below:

   ```
   save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void Onclick(View v){
        //extract data from user.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
       }
   });
   ```

   the problem is recyclerView not updating until relaunching Activity, although
   `onResume`, and `onStart` exists with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: you need to put more code, for example fragment code and XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BroadcastReciever` to receive notification when save button is pressed. For example register it inside your `Activity`:

```
private void registerReciver() {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // broadcast receiver is fired reload your data here
        }
    };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("action");
    this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Call `registerReciver();` in your `onCreate()` method, now you can launch it from `save` button:

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction("action");
                        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

After pressing `save` button `onReceive` should be called. Now you can fetch data again and reload. Even using `Intent` you can pass data to `Activity` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

If you are using a `Fragment`, it should be local to some `Activity` (hopefully the one which holds your `RecyclerView`).  From inside that `Fragment` you can access the `Activity` containing it with `getActivity()`, along with any of its public members and methods.

Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631408/android-fragment-getactivity-sometimes-returns-null) for more info.

Comment: You can therefore create a method in your `Activity` called `getRecViewAdapter()` and from your `Fragment` call: `getActivity().getRecViewAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`