# adapter instance gone in fragment with listview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I am pretty new to fragments and do have an issue atm.

My onResume() method, calls a database-helper class, which returns some simple objects to following listener method:

```
    @Override
public void onHistoryLoaded(List<Entry> entrieslist) {
    Logging.d(TAG, "onHistoryLoadedListener called");
    if (entrieslist != null) {
        this.entries = entrieslist;
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Logging.d(TAG, "adapter is null, recreating");
            this.mAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.history_row, entrieslist);
            registerForContextMenu(lv);
            mAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(entries);

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    } else {
        Logging.e(TAG, "onHistoryLoaded: returned entries are empty");
    }

}
```

as you see, my instance variable mAdapter is initialized if it's null. This works great so far.
My issue comes as soon as the configuration changes (e.g. user gets into landscape). Data is displayed fine (as onResume and onHistoryLoaded is called fine too and tells that the adapter has been null and therefore is freshly created).
However, when I call .clear() on the adapter (which works fine in portrait mode) I get a nullpointerexception because the mAdapter variable instance is null. How can this happen? I do nothing in a background thread or something else. it shouldn't be null at this point.

I am running out of ideas atm. Thanks in advance.

My LogCat errors:

```
02-05 00:17:22.430: E/HistoryFragment(25174): mAdapter is null?
02-05 00:17:22.430: W/System.err(25174): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 00:17:22.445: W/System.err(25174):        at com.sapps.savetodrive.HistoryFragment.cleanHistory(HistoryFragment.java:361)
02-05 00:17:22.445: W/System.err(25174):        at com.sapps.savetodrive.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:103)
02-05 00:17:22.445: W/System.err(25174):        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java)
02-05 00:17:22.445: W/System.err(25174):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:351)
02-05 00:17:22.445: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java)
02-05 00:17:22.450: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java)
02-05 00:17:22.455: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java)
02-05 00:17:22.455: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java)
02-05 00:17:22.455: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java)
02-05 00:17:22.475: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowPopup.onItemClick(ActionMenuPresenter.java)
02-05 00:17:22.480: W/System.err(25174):        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java)
02-05 00:17:22.480: W/System.err(25174):        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java)
02-05 00:17:22.485: W/System.err(25174):        at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java)
02-05 00:17:22.485: W/System.err(25174):        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java)
02-05 00:17:22.485: W/System.err(25174):        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java)
02-05 00:17:22.485: W/System.err(25174):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
02-05 00:17:22.490: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
02-05 00:17:22.495: W/System.err(25174):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
02-05 00:17:22.495: W/System.err(25174):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

following code, is where the error occurs (just a bit restructured, it occurs at mAdapter.clear() ). This returns mAdapter == null is TRUE!

```
    public void cleanHistory() {
    if (mAdapter == null)
        Logging.e(TAG, "ADAPTER IS NULL WHEN CLEANING?!");
    else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        lastUndoAction = FLAG_UNDO_CLEANALL;
        mUndoBarController.showUndoBar(false,
                getString(R.string.item_allremoved), null);
    }
}
```

onResume ..

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (lv != null && helper != null) {

        Logging.d(TAG, "onResume(), lv and helper aren't null");
        helper.getAllEntries();
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, `mAdapter` can't be null there. Please post your LogCat errors, so we can see where this tricky NPE actually occurs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5nEaceLS Here it is... if i check for mAdapter == null it returns true..

Comment: Where do you print `mAdapter is null?`? It's interesting that those are warnings not errors... What line is 361, is it `mAdapter.clear()`?

Comment: Yes it is. I attached some source in an edit on the op, where mAdapter == null returns true. but ONLY after a configuration change!

when starting the app in landscape or portrait without configuration change, it works as it should.

Comment: Can you post your `onResume()` method so we can see exactly how the method calls are set up?

Comment: done. and my log says, helper.getAllEntries() is called, as well as "adapter is null, recreating" in the loadedlistener...

Comment: @Aeefire `onHistoryLoaded()` and `cleanHistory()` aren't being called from `onResume()` Based on the trace, `cleanHistory()` is being called from `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: onHistoryLoaded is getting called by onResume() as helper.getAllEntries() calls listener.onHistoryLoaded(result) when it's done. 
cleanHistory() is invoked by the user (clicking the menu) as already described. (and has to be after onHistoryLoaded() as there is no background thread going on and everything is blocking the ui thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixxed now. The question was really somewhere else.
Android seems to instantiate its own instances of the fragment objects. 
So what happened was, that my call in OnOptionsItemCrated() on the fragment instance, which was retrieved by the viewpager was basically an empty instance of the fragment, which didn't have the onAttach() onActivityCreated() stuff called, as it wasn't attached to any activity yet.
So my "workaround" (for this especially stupid problem imho) was to use the solution suggested here: [getFragmentByTag from Switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727173/support-fragmentpageradapter-holds-reference-to-old-fragments/9744146#9744146)

What it does, is basically "generate the generated tag" inside the viewpager to retrieve the currently displayed (and attached) fragment from the fragmentmanager.

```
private String getFragmentTag(int pos){
    return "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+pos;
}
```

so my solution in onOptionsItemSelected finally looks like this:

```
    case R.id.menu_cleanhistory:
            ((HistoryFragment) MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(
                            "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":1"))
                    .cleanHistory();
           return true;
```

and believe it or not - it works.