# Menu item null when calling method in fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, menuitem

My app uses a `ViewPager` in portrait mode and a dual-fragment layout in landscape.

I am trying to kick off an `AsyncTask`, that is in the `Fragment`, from  `Activity`.  The `AsyncTask` is normally started from a menu item in the `Actionbar`, but I have a need to start it programatically from the `Activity`.

The menu item is an `ImageView` and I'm animating it while the `AsyncTask` is running.  The code I have works fine in the dual-fragment landscape view, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the menu item when in portrait mode.

**Activity**

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private static List<Integer> mIds;
    private static SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager); //view pager exists, so we are using the portait layout

        if (mViewPager != null)
        {
            mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            mIds.add(0);
            mIds.add(1);
            mIds.add(2);

        }
        else //in landscape
        {           
            ListFragment lf = (ListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentList);

            if (lf == null)
                lf = new ListFragment();

            DetailFragment df = (DetailFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDetail);

            if (df == null)
            {
                df = new DetailFragment();
                df.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());   
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentList, lf).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentDetail, df).commit();

        }

        final MyFragmentPagerAdapter fpa = (MyFragmentPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter();
        ListFragment lf2 = (ListFragment)fpa.getFragment(0);

        //this works if I use:
        //(ListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentList);

        lf2.RunTask();
    }       

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {        
            if (index == 0)
            {
                ListFragment lf = ListFragment.newInstance();
                mPageReferenceMap.put(index, lf);
                return lf;
            }
            else
            {
                DetailFragment df = DetailFragment.newInstance(mIds.get(index-1));
                mPageReferenceMap.put(index, df);
                return df;
        }  

        public Fragment getFragment(int key) {
            return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
        }

        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {  
             return 4;
        }
   }  
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ListingFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    private MenuItem refreshItem;

    public static ListingFragment newInstance() {

        ListingFragment lf = new ListingFragment();

        return lf;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listing_layout, container, false);
    }

    private void StartAnimation() {
       final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       final ImageView ivRefresh = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_view, null);

       final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.refresh);
       ivRefresh.startAnimation(rotation);

        //this is null
       refreshItem.setActionView(ivRefresh);
    }

    public void StopAnimation()
    {
        if (refreshItem != null && refreshItem.getActionView() != null) 
        {
            refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            refreshItem.setActionView(null);
        }
    }

    public void RunTask()
    {
        new GetItems().execute();
    }

    private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
          StartAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
        {
            ...
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
        {
            StopAnimation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.keyword_menu, menu);

        refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.get);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) 
    {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.get) {
            gi = new GetItems(getActivity(), null);
            gi.execute();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following link provide you with your answer on how to avoid the nullpointer exception.
Fragment's instances may be recreated by the system at any time, that's why it's not easy to "hold a reference to them". You have to use the fragmentmanager.

[adapter instance gone in fragment with listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697436/adapter-instance-gone-in-fragment-with-listview)