# Remove Fragment from PageAdapter completly

Tags: android, android-fragments

**PROBLEM**

My `PageAdapter` is constructed in a specific way that previous pages have impact on rest of them. Because of that I sometimes need to change position and clean my `Fragment` so the user wont have previous choices on it. The positioning I already solved but problem with "cleaning" the `Fragment` is still a giving me a headache.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to remove `Fragment` from `PageAdapter` and get rid of its state?
Or is there some better way to deal with it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android

Comment: @SheetalSuryan already tried that :C

Comment: could you build sample app send it to me, will see and try fix it

Comment: Answer to this question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928732/removing-fragments-from-fragmentstatepageradapter/