# getFragmentManager() returns null on second call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I've been for learning how to code in Android, but I am having some problems.

Right now, I do not really know how to finish a `Fragment`. I mean, when I use the method `getActivity().finish()`, my `Activity` should `finish()`. I've been reading about it, and it is not correct at all. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing):

> Also, onDestroy() isn't a destructor. It doesn't actually destroy the
>   object. It's just a method that's called based on a certain state. So
>   your instance is still alive and very well* after the superclass's
>   onDestroy() runs and returns.Android keeps processes around in case
>   the user wants to restart the app, this makes the startup phase
>   faster. The process will not be doing anything and if memory needs to
>   be reclaimed, the process will be killed

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727173/support-fragmentpageradapter-holds-reference-to-old-fragments/9745935#9745935):

> Consider that you then background your application, and then it gets
>   killed. When you come back, Android will remember that you used to
>   have Fragments A, B and C in the fragment manager and so it recreates
>   them for you and then adds them. **However, the ones that are added to
>   the fragment manager now are NOT the ones you have in your fragments
>   list in your Activity.**

In my case, I have two activities and two fragments. The first time that I used this process it worked perfectly.

- I call to my second `Activity` from the first one using an `Intent`
- I call to the first `Fragment`
- I call from the first `Fragment` to the second one

The problem is that when I press the button "reset" that it finish my `Activity` from the second `Fragment` (so it goes to the first `Activity`). After this, I repeat the entire process and it actually works but when I try to implement the next line to keep updating data:

```
private BroadcastReceiver estadoIAReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    //Cuando cambia el estado de indoor atlas actualizo la interfaz con sus propiedades
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("VFragment", "Cambio estado IA");

        //Ejecutar metodo de un fragment desde una actividad
        infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);
        infoF.actualizaInfoEstadoIA();
        infoF.onResume();
    }
};
```

It fails because `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);`
returns `null`. So, basically my question is; is `infoF` trying to access to the same `Fragment` from the first time but it does not exist so it returns `null`?

Comment: I might not understand your question, but if the fragment is not in FragmentManager (is null), then you should add a new one to it because it was destroyed,and removed from Fragmentmanager

Comment: I mean, the code works the first time (so during the first time that i execute it, i do not get "null"). So i do not really know why do i get it @Bryan

Comment: I think you meant @VladMatvienko. Anyway, show more code; there is nothing in the code you provided that shows why `getFragmentMangager()` would return `null`. Also this line: "I call from the first `Fragment` to the second one" sounds suspicious. You should not be calling from one `Fragment` to another, the `Activity` should handle transactions between fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, some days ago I could find my error.

The solution is simple:

- Just create a new Bundle variable as a global variable

Bundle datosGuardados;

- to store the data of savedInstanceState

datosGuardados = savedInstanceState;

- and finally just check if it is null before than using any getFragmentManager

if (datosGuardados != null)
                infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);