# FragmentStatePagerAdapter view pager fragments not showing after activity recreate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-pageradapter

When my `Activity` gets recreated via orientation change or if "Don't keep activities" is turned on in developer settings, my `ViewPager` that has 
`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` doesn't recreate fragments.

this is activity `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    pagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    presenter.onCreate();
  }
```

this is FragmentStatePager:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

  public MyFoodaPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  public void init(List<Fragment> initFrags) {
    fragments.addAll(initFrags);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public void update(Fragment fragment, int position) {
    fragments.set(position, fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (!fragments.contains(object)) {
      return POSITION_NONE; // replace
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
  }

  public void clear(){
    fragments.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Title "+position; // TODO: 25/10/2017  
  }
}
```

Since `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` saves currently selected fragment and the one's right next to it, if I only have 2 fragments in pager and Activity gets recreated, changing fragment list and calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't do anything.

`getItem(int position)` doesn't get triggered in `PagerAdapter` at all after activity gets recreated. If I have 3+ fragments in the pager and 1st one is selected then moving to 3rd page will render that fragment and moving back to 1st fragment will finally render 1st fragment. If I have only 2 fragments in pager then moving between does nothing, they do not get rendered.

Also what I'm seeing after Activity is recreated. `FragmentManager` has those 2 fragments with reference numbers lets say (Fragment1@1000) and (Fragment2@1001), when I add new fragments into `private List<Fragment> fragments`, (Fragment1@1050) and (Fragment2@1051) in pager adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, fragmentManager does not update its fragments, it will still have those old fragments in.

EDIT: I think I found my problem [support FragmentPagerAdapter holds reference to old fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727173/support-fragmentpageradapter-holds-reference-to-old-fragments)
Which says in short, even in the comments, is to never hold reference to fragments outside of PagerAdapter.

Comment: where did you call init(List<Fragment> initFrags) method ??

Comment: When I get data from server I parse it and create fragments from it which I then pass to PagerAdapter via `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to update the Fragment View when you are moving between Fragments whether its two or more than that.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        //getPlanListData();
    }
}
```